# How to get the value of DateRangePicker (syncfusion) on react js

Tags: reactjs, syncfusion, daterangepicker

I have a date range picker from Syncfusion, I installed the package and import the component to my react project. I'm pretty much new to DateRangePicker, so I wonder how can I get the value of the DateRangePicker.

here is my code

```
import React from 'react'
import './DateRangePicker.css'
import {DateRangePickerComponent} from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-calendars'

function DateRangePicker(){
    return(
        <>
            <DateRangePickerComponent></DateRangePickerComponent>
        </>
    )
}

export default DateRangePicker
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the value of `DateRangePickerComponent` by pass a prop: [change](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/api/daterangepicker/#change)

```
function DateRangePicker(){
    const onChange = (props) => {
        const stateDate = props.startDate;
        const endDate = props.endDate;

    };
    return(
        <>
            <DateRangePickerComponent change={onChange} />
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps.

1. Create an event handler in the component & pass that to *syncfusion calendar* using `change` property.
2. Then you can directly print the date with configured date format by using the `text` property in the event object.

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { DateRangePickerComponent } from "@syncfusion/ej2-react-calendars";

import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const [date, updateDate] = useState();

  const onChange = (e) => {
    updateDate(e.text);
  }; // the event handler

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <DateRangePickerComponent change={onChange} />
      <div>Date - {date}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/syncfusion-calendar-gc7ks?file=/src/App.js:0-422

Answer (score 0):

By accessing the component instance via ref property, we can get the selected value. Refer the below code.

```
function DateRangePicker() {
    function onClick(){
      console.log(dateRangeRef.value)
    }
    let dateRangeRef =  dateRange => dateRangeRef = dateRange;
    return (
      <>
        <DateRangePickerComponent ref={dateRangeRef} />
        <input type="button" value="getSelectedValue" onClick={onClick} />
      </>
    );
  }
  
  render(<DateRangePicker />, document.getElementById('sample'));
```

Please find the sample below.

Sample link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hykg6v

API documentation link: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/api/daterangepicker#value