# Reactjs How to get the value of Start date and End date?

Tags: reactjs, syncfusion, syncfusion-calendar

How can I get the value of start date and end date? I use:

```js
import { DateRangePickerComponent } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-calendars';
```

This is a duplicate question because I want to get the start and end date separately.

```js
import { DateRangePickerComponent } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-calendars';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const [startdate, setStartDate] = useState("");
const [enddate, setEndDate] = useState("");
const onChangedate = (props) => {
  const stateDate = props.startDate;
  const endDate = props.endDate;
  setStartDate(stateDate)
  setEndDate(endDate)
};

const handleUpdateButton = async ()=> {
  console.log(startdate, enddate) // I just want to print here the start date and end date
}

<Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={6} lg={6} style={{padding: 15, paddingBottom: 0, alignItems: 'center'}}>
  <DateRangePickerComponent id="daterangepicker" change={onChangedate} placeholder='Select a range' style={{paddingTop: 10, fontSize: 16}}/>
</Grid>

<Grid item xs={12} style={{padding: 8}}>
 <Button onClick={handleUpdateButton} variant="contained"color="primary" fullWidth>
   Apply Filters
 </Button>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using syncfusion components? Could you share an executable of your code into codesandbox?

Comment: yes i am using syncfusion

Comment: sadly I dont know how to use codesandbox

Comment: What did you import at the top of this component for using `DateRangePickerComponent`?

Comment: `import { DateRangePickerComponent } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-calendars';`

Comment: I mean styles. What did you import for styles?

Comment: `import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';`

Comment: Could you please update your question and share the full code of your component?

Comment: @MajidMohammadi done

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the value of DateRangePicker (syncfusion) on react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67868048/how-to-get-the-value-of-daterangepicker-syncfusion-on-react-js)

Comment: @MajidMohammadi , No, I just want to get separately the start and end date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235429/discussion-between-majid-mohammadi-and-kaito).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the dates separately with `startDate` and `endDate` of  **`change`** event from `DateRangePickerComponent`:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { DateRangePickerComponent } from "@syncfusion/ej2-react-calendars";

const App = () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState();
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState();

  function convertDate(inputFormat) {
    function pad(s) { return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s; }
    var d = new Date(inputFormat)
    return [pad(d.getMonth()+1),pad(d.getDate()), d.getFullYear()].join('-')
  }

  const onChange = (e) => {
    let startDate = convertDate(e.startDate);
    let endDate = convertDate(e.endDate);
    setStartDate(startDate);
    setEndDate(endDate);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <DateRangePickerComponent change={onChange} />
      <div>
        {startDate} - {endDate}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image: Edit syncfusion-calendar (forked)]